# Dotfuscator for Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight-5.0, dotfuscator

Visual Studio version = Visual studio 2010 premium

as we all know silverlight application generate **.XAP** file if we change extension to **.ZIP** we can get all dlls which is use in Application and Application Dll also if we use reflector and disassemble the dlls file user can get the code . i want to protect this kind of stuf.

can we put **Dotfuscator** in between the process of build and generate xap file

Build (generate dlls) -> Dotfuscator -> generating XAP file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to obfuscate Silverlight applications is to build the XAP package and then run Dotfuscator on the XAP file itself(ie, use the stand-alone GUI and add the XAP file to a new project). Note that this requires  Dotfuscator Professional Edition.